# Java client and a C++ server send and receive via TCP Socket

Tags: java, c++, ruby, sockets, send

I have a C++ server and two clients (ruby and java).
Everything is running on a 64-bit linux-machine (java 1.7.0_17)
The ruby client is fully working, but the java version makes problems.

In Java I tried to send a String from the client to the server. Actually the Server received the entire String, but the server thinks there is still something more to receive.

The ruby client looks a little bit like this:

```
socket = TCPSocket.open(@options[:host],@options[:port])
test = "Hello, World"
socket.puts test
socket.shutdown 1
response = socket.gets
```

Everything here is working fine. The ruby client sends a string. The server receives that string and sends a reply.

The Java Version looks like:

```
String ip = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 6686;
java.net.Socket socket = new java.net.Socket(ip,port);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

String msg = "Hello, world!";

//send
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);
pw.print(msg);
pw.flush();
// I also tried: out.write(msg); out.flush(); nothing changed

//receive the reply
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
char[] buffer = new char[300];
int count = br.read(buffer, 0, 300);
String reply = new String(buffer, 0, count);
System.out.println(reply);

socket.close();
```

On the other side there is a C++ Server:

```
string receive(int SocketFD) {
   char buffer[SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE];
   int recv_count;

   // empty messagestring
   string message = "";

   // empty buffer
   memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

   while ((recv_count = recv(SocketFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0)) > 0) {
      /*if (recv_count == -1) {
         cout << "failed." << endl;
         break;
      }*/
      cout << recv_count << endl;
      if (ECHO_SOCKETS) cout << "received: " << buffer << endl;

      message.append(buffer);
      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

      if (ECHO_SOCKETS) cout << "message is now: " << message << endl;

   }
   return message;
}
```

The server output from the Java-message is:

```
13
received: Hello, world!
message is now: Hello, world!
```

and then nothing happens.
The problem is that:

```
recv(SocketFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0)
```

is catched in an endless loop (or something like that).
If I kill the Java-client process or I type something like:

```
pw.print(msg);
out.close();
```

the output on the server side is:

```
_sending reply: "Request unrecognized/invalid" request="Hello, world!"
send reply success
now close connection
```

This output is right (except "send reply success"), but in case of adding:

```
out.close();
```

the client can't receive the reply of the server. Because the Socket is closed.

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:864)
at MyServer.writeMessage(MyServer.java:56)
at MyServer.test(MyServer.java:42)
at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:30)
```

## **Edit**

I tried to call pw.flush(); and different delimiters like "\n", "\r", "\r\n" and "\n\r" but the server still thinks there is still something to read. I also tried to use DatagramSockets:

```
java.net.DatagramSocket dSocket = new java.net.DatagramSocket();
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
String msg = "Hello, world!";
byte[] buf = msg.getBytes();
java.net.DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 6686);
```

But the server can't accept the packet.

## **Solution**

The ruby-client does something like a socket.shutdownOutput(); (ruby: socket.shutdown 1) after the call of puts. I changed the java-client-code:

```
out.write(msg);
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

and it works!

As @Charly said: I have to define a "protocol". In my case I'm not allowed to change any communication related code (in the server and the ruby-client) because this functionality is used by a another group of researchers. So I've to modify my java-client in that way, that it does the **exact** same things at the **exact** same time as the ruby-client (something like a protocol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrintWriter buffer (when autoflush is true) is only flushed by calling println or printf. Calling print may not flush the buffer ([Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)). Try calling println or use a OutputStreamWriter directly and flush().
Be aware of using the right charset (You can set it up in OutputStreamWriter constructor).

Comment: I already used pw.flush() but nothing was changed. Now I tried to use OutputStreamWriter directly:
out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); ... and out.write(msg); out.flush(); but same result.

Comment: I changed the java-client source

Comment: I really don't know c++ but shouldn't you have some kind of delimiter to indicate the end of the message to the server ? As i see it, your server only send the echo when the connection is closed... For example the readLine() on a BufferedReader in Java will only return when reading a \n or a \r.

Comment: I' already tried something like: "Hello, world!\n" but the server prints all out and hangs at the same line.
As I mentioned at the end of my post, I think I need a special delimiter, but why does it work in ruby? And of course I don't what to write the server-code depending on the programming language used by the client.

Comment: Of course you cannot write a server based on the programming language used by the client. Both must be compliant, that's why you need to define a kind of "protocol" between the two. If you decide that the client must send a String and a "\n", that's how it is and you do the same in Ruby and Java. In your c++ code, just test whenever this symbol appears and you can go out of your loop and send the reply. About the Ruby, I don't really know but it seems that "puts" write a newline sequence at the end.

Comment: So, puts makes a newline. I tried "\n", "\r", "\n\r" and "\r\n" nothing helped. BUT I realized that the ruby-client does something like a socket.shutdownOutput(); (ruby: socket.shutdown 1) after the call of puts. I changed the java-client-code: out.write(msg);socket.shutdownOutput(); and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Close the stream respectively flush it in a way like this:

```
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOut.writeUTF(s);
dataOut.flush();
```

Comment: Hi Misch, DataOutputStream, writeUTF(msg) and flush(); doesn't work.
recv_count is 15! on the server (I would accept 13 or 14). And the output: cout << "received: " << buffer << endl; is empty. There are no characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((recv_count = recv(SocketFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0)) > 0) {
      if (recv_count == -1) {
```

I don't know what your problem is but this code is certainly nonsense. It is impossible for the inner test ever to succeed.

Comment: You are right. It's just an old code fragment. You can ignore it.