# Java Send array of processes via tcp to server

Tags: java, tcp, server

I am programming a external Taskmanager and i need to send the process list via tcp to my server application. But i don't know how to start and how this works.

Edit: 
I have the processlist i only have to send it via TCP to the Serverside.

Thx for your help.

Comment: You'll need to write OS-specific code. You can start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a processlist, then it's not so hard to make client-server logic for your purposes with Java. First of all, you need to make a server side:

```
public class ServerSide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
            Socket skt = myServerSocket.accept();
            List<Process> objects = null;
            try {
                ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
                try {
                    Object object = objectInput.readObject();
                    objects =  (ArrayList<Process>) object;
                    System.out.println(objects);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {             
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Wich will use a ServerSocket to listen on specified port, in this case is 9999. Then connection accepted (take a look at myServerSocket.accept(), it stops the execution, until any connection is accepted), it creates a Socket and you can get it's InputStream and get an object from it. In this example server stops after first accepted connection, you should make it accept any number of connections with infinity loop for example.

When you have a server, you can make a client side, which will send a list of Processes to the Server:

```
public class ClientSide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9999);

            ArrayList<Process> my =  new ArrayList<Process>();
            my.add(new Process("Test1"));
            my.add(new Process("Test2"));
            try
            {
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                objectOutput.writeObject(my);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, you'll create a Socket by youself, give an eddress and port number to it, where it will send a data. Then you can get an OutputStream and pass your data through it. In example above, you pass an Array of Process object instances. The Process class looks like:

```
public class Process implements Serializable {

    private String processName = null;

    public Process(String processName) {
        this.processName = processName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return processName;
    }
}
```

The main thing in case of Process class, it should implement the Serializable interface. In that case, you don't need to make some logic for it's serialization.

But if you have to make a client with Java, but not a server, then it could be a little bit harder. You may take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902898/java-client-and-a-c-server-send-and-receive-via-tcp-socket), to see some kind of example, how Java-client communicates with C++ server. Anyway, in Java-part you should use a Socket and it's OutputStream, only the data representation will differ.